# how to solve TS2322 while sending props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am working with a OpenWeatherMap with React/TS. I need to get the weather data in the App.tsx component and pass it to the WeatherCard component as props.

I created a template for weather JSON in types.ts:

```
export type WeatherDataObj = {
    coord: { lon: number, lat: number },
    weather: [{ id: number, main: string, description: string, icon: string }],
    base: string,
    main: { temp: number, feels_like: number, temp_min: number, temp_max: number, pressure: number, humidity: number, sea_level: number, grnd_level: number },
    visibility: number,
    wind: { speed: number, deg: number, gust: number },
    clouds: { all: number },
    dt: number,
    sys: { type: number, id: number, country: string, sunrise: number, sunset: number },
    timezone: number,
    id: number,
    name: string,
    cod: number
  }
```

The App.tsx itself:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import WeatherCard from './components/WeatherCard/WeatherCard';
import { WeatherDataObj } from './types/types';


function App() {

  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState<WeatherDataObj>({} as WeatherDataObj);

  const getWeather = () => {

    fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Madrid&lang=en&appid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&units=metric`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => setWeatherData(data));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getWeather();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SearchPanel />
      <WeatherCard
        weatherData={weatherData} />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

WeatherCard.tsx:

```
import { WeatherDataObj } from '../../types/types';

const WeatherCard = (weatherData: WeatherDataObj) => {

return ()
        <>
          <p>City: {weatherData.name}</p>
          <p>Temperature: {weatherData.main.temp}</p>
         // etc.
        </>
    )

}
export default WeatherCard;
```

The error code and text:

```
TS2322: Type '{ weatherData: WeatherDataObj; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & WeatherDataObj'.
  Property 'weatherData' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & WeatherDataObj'.
    28 |
    29 |       <WeatherCard
  > 30 |         weatherData={weatherData} />
       |         ^^^^^^^^^^^
    31 |
    32 |     </div>
    33 |   );
```

The error occurs only if I pass data to another component through props. If I display data in the App.tsx component, then everything is ok.

Stackovewflow search did not solve the problem.

Comment: Your type `WeatherDataObj` doesn't have a property `weatherData`

Comment: Your component props are the individual properties of a `WeatherDataObj`, if you intended to pass the whole object as a single prop named `weatherData` your component definition is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Define your `WeatherCard` component like the following:

```
import { WeatherDataObj } from '../../types/types';

const WeatherCard = ({ weatherData }: { weatherData: WeatherDataObj }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <p>City: {weatherData.name}</p>
      <p>Temperature: {weatherData.main.temp}</p>
      // etc.
    </>
  );
}
export default WeatherCard;
```

When you call a component like `WeatherCard` with some props, these props are all send to just one object conventionally named `props`:

```
const WeatherCard = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <>
      <p>City: {weatherData.name}</p>
      <p>Temperature: {weatherData.main.temp}</p>
      // etc.
    </>
  );
}
```

In your case you define the `props` object to be the type of `WeatherDataObj`.

This would work if you called the `WeatherCard` like the following:

```
<WeatherCard
  coord={...}
  base={...}
  weather={...}
  ... 
/>
```

Comment: You are a magician! Could you please explain what is happening?

Comment: @АнтонБлаговещенский yeah sorry for the late. I'm going to update the answer now